# Coin flipping program that prints percentage for either heads or tails/python

Tags: python

So I'm new to coding and I'm trying to write a coin flipping program. It has to flip the coin 1000 times and give the percentage for heads, then I have to flip it 50000 more times and get the percentage for heads again. This is all I have right now I have no idea where to go from here.

```
def flipCoin():
  heads=0
  for i in range(1000):
    coin=random.randint(1,2)
    if random.randint==1:
      print ("Heads")
      heads+=1
      percent=(heads/10)*100
      print (percent)
    else:
      print
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. Post the whole code.

Comment: You're on the right track. Think about what you should divide `heads` by. Right now you're dividing it by 10 but that isn't right.

Comment: It is part of a bigger program I'm writing, but that's all I have for that one part

Comment: If you only need to print the total amount of heads, I would move the print statement outside of the for loop. It's going to take up a lot of time and make it run slowly. Also, you're comparing `random.randint` to `1` instead of `coin`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.
In this case, slow down -- identify and correct one problem at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the gist of the code you're trying to write:

```
flip a coin
see if it's heads, add to a global counter
divide global counter by total number of tries (this is the percentage)
```

All you've gotta do is do it for both 1000 tries and 50000 tries. From the code snippet you already posted, you've got the flipping and the counting right - now just fix the percentage and run it for both 1000 and 50000 attempts. :) Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this would be to add a **parameter** to your function.

For example, you can define your flipCoin() function with the parameter `num_of_flips`

```
def flipCoin(num_of_flips):
    # function body
```

Then, whenever you call the function. You can pass in values as **arguments**. Like so:

```
flipCoin(100) # flip coin 100 times
flipCoin(5000) # flip coin 5000 times
```

Here's my full flipCoin() function:

```
def flipCoin(num_of_flips):
    heads = 0
    for i in range(num_of_flips):
        coin=random.randint(1, 2)
        if coin==1:
            heads += 1

    percent = heads / num_of_flips
    print(percent)

flipCoin(100) # flip coin 100 times
flipCoin(5000) # flip coin 5000 times
```

Also, you need to get your math right for percent. Percent should equal **heads divided by total flips**. That's what I've done in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to stackoverflow.

First thing: since you need to flip a coin n number of times, why not reflect that in your function, like?

```
def flipCoin(times):
    # ...
    for i in range(times):
```

Next: to make the decision about heads or tails all we need is one option that is 'falsey'(meaning an implicit bool cast evaluates to False) and one that isn't. `random.randint(0,1)` gives us just that, so we can use this random integer as our condition for heads:

```
if random.randint(0,1):
    heads += 1
```

And just print the results:

```
print('heads percentage: %05.2f' % (100 * float(heads) / times) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've improved your code. My python knowledge isn't so great either but here it is:

```
import random

def flipCoin():
    heads = 0 # track heads amount
    tails = 0 # track tails amount
    headspercent = 0 # heads percentage
    tailspercent = 0 # tails percentage

    for i in range(1000): # run the experiment 1000 times
      coin=random.randint(1,2) # assign a value to coin, either 1 or 2

      if coin==1: # if coin value is assigned as 1
          heads+=1 # increase heads count by 1
      else: # if coin value is assigned something other than 1
          tails+=1 # increase tails count by 1

    headspercent = heads / 10.0 # since we're rolling 1000 times, /10 will give percentage
    tailspercent = 100.0 - headspercent # no need to recalculate 100 - heads = tails %

    print("Heads percent: " + str(headspercent)) # printing the values on screen
    print("Tails percent: " + str(tailspercent)) # converting numbers to string by str()



flipCoin() # calling the function
```

Here's the output of the code:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Heads percent: 50.6
Tails percent: 49.4
```

I've explained which line does what in the code. I hope this answer helps you to understand the topic better.

Edit: I've tried to keep it as simple as possible, there are more advanced methods to approach this problem.